# Creating solid color icons on macOS leads to off-color pixels on the bottom

Tags: macos, icons, finder

I've been trying to create icons without transparent backgrounds, but I keep getting strange results. For example, when I make icons with white backgrounds, their bottom rows will wind up with yellow pixels.

[image: screen shot of info box showing yellow pixels on bottom]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a square PNG file with solid white.
2. Right-click on any application and select Get Info.
3. Click-and-drag the PNG file to the application's icon in the upper-left.

Notice the icon has a strip of yellow pixels on the bottom.

---

I was having [trouble creating Finder icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71405128/finder-toolbar-icons-are-jagged-or-anti-aliased-on-non-retina-displays) to match the macOS aesthetic, so as a test, I tried making icons without transparency. But then I ended up with a new problem.

Comment: What application are you using to create your "square PNG file with solid white"?  I used Photoshop to create the "square PNG file with solid white" and I have no strip of yellow pixels on the bottom.  https://i.imgur.com/OvjlLQJ.png?1

Comment: Thanks for the repro attempt. I used Pixelmator Pro. Try it with this file, I was able to reproduce the error: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Solid_white.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're talking about is a quirk with the Apple Icon Image format. If you read the [Wikipedia entry on ICNS files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format) there is this known issue: "if the last value is a repeating byte (see Compression). Potentially, up to 130 pixels can lack the blue channel value." So, in RGB, if you remove B, you get yellow, which is likely what you're seeing.